# redirect the output to terminal to a file in a batch file

Tags: bash

```
for((i=1;i<15;i=i+1));
   do
   mpirun -np $i a.out
   done
```

In `a.out` there are `printf`s which will output some medium results to the screen. How to redirect them to a file named `output.txt`?

Comment: Have you tried `... mpirun -np $i a.out >output.txt` ?

Comment: `(mpirun -np $i a.out) >> output.txt` will run the command in a subshell redirecting the `stdout` (what `printf` writes to) to the file `output.txt`. While a subshell isn't entirely necessary, it can facilitate writing all output at once instead of piecemeal. Before the loop, if you need to truncate the file, use `:>output.txt` which effectively truncates the file to an empty state. **Note:** in Linux bash scripts are "*shell scripts*" in DOS/windoze you have "*batch files*".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from my comment, you have several options on how to redirect the output of your shell script calling `mpirun` and `a.out` to an output file.

1. the most common and rudimentary is simply to redirect the entire output of the shell script to the output file, e.g. `bash scriptname.sh > output.txt`;
2. the second option would be to redirect the output of the `mpirun -np $i a.out` command itself which would write to the output file 14 times in the example you show, e.g. `mpirun -np $i a.out >> output.txt`, note the `>>` redirection to append to the file (also, as noted you will want to truncate `output.txt` before the loop if you need to write to an empty file each time);
3. similar to `2.` above you could execute the `mpirun` command in a subshell, which buys you little in your example, but is an option and helpful in certain circumstances; and
4. an optimal way of redirecting just the output produced by the loop within the shell script to `output.txt` is to use a *brace-enclosed group* to allow a single redirection of the entire output produced by the loop, e.g. `{ for ((...)); do ... done } > output.txt`

For example, if your `mpirun ...` command produces output to `stdout` (similar to the simple example below)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char *s = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "default";

    printf ("%s\n", s);

    return 0;
}
```

(compiled as `echoarg`)

An example shell script mimicking your loop and using a brace-enclosed-group to redirect to `output.txt` could be written as:

```
#!/bin/bash

exefile="${1:-./bin/echoarg}"   ## executable to call
outfile="${2:-output.txt}"      ## output file name
:> "$outfile"                   ## truncate outfile

[ -x "$exefile" ] || {
    printf "error: file not executable '%s'\n" "$exefile"
    exit 1
}

## braced group encosing for loop redirected to outfile
{
for ((i = 1; i < 15; i++))
do
    ./bin/echoarg "$i"
done
} > "$outfile"
```

**Example Use/Output/Resulting File**

```
$ ./echoarg.sh ./bin/echoarg dat/outfile.txt
```

and

```
$ cat dat/outfile.txt
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.